# WebStorm: unresolved variable or type altough library is loaded

Tags: javascript, webstorm

There is a warning 'unresolved variable or type' although the corresponding library 'TweenMax' is loaded like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

The code snipped, which the warning contains (object TweenMax and Power1):

```
TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
                    scrollTo : { y: finalScroll, autoKill:true },
                        ease: Power1.easeOut,   
                        autoKill: true,
                        overwrite: 5

                    });
```

The app work well despite the warning. I have already invalidated and rebuilt caches in the WebStorm.

Any ideas to solve this warning?

Comment: Do you have **local not-minified version** of that library somewhere in your project (or referenced as JavaScript library in IDE settings)? If you only have such <`script` reference to CDN or any other external URL -- IDE will not fetch them for you).

Comment: The library is created by GreenSock [link](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) and also referenced in the js library settings of the IDE. It is also possible to download the library as a zip file and to import into the IDE.